# create a dependencies for services with systemd

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, systemd

im trying to create a ServiceB that start after ServiceA starts.

This is what i tried to do :

ServiceA file:

```
[Unit] 
Description=ServiceA 
After=network.target
 
[Service] 
ExecStartPre=running some shell script.... 
ExecStart=running some shell script....
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID 
KillMode=process 
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255 
TimeoutStopSec=10
 
[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

first ServiceB file try:

```
[Unit] 
Description=ServiceB 
After=ServiceA.service
Requires=ServiceA.service
    
[Service] 
ExecStart=running some shell script.... 

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

second ServiceB file try:

```
[Unit] 
Description=ServiceB 
After=ServiceA.service
Requires=ServiceA.service

[Service] 
ExecStart=running some shell script.... 

[Install]
WantedBy=ServiceA.service
```

the first try works, but only at startup, but when i stop the services with
systemctl stop ServiceA
systemctl stop ServiceA

and then try to start the again ServiceA
systemctl start ServiceA

i thought that ServiceB should start too (it still enabled)

what can be the problem ?

** i dont want to use Wants= in the ServiceA file, i want that ServiceB will manage it .

Comment: Your `systemd stop ServiceA` then `systemd start ServiceA` works fine on my computer (version 2 of ServiceB), though I adapted it and tested with --user. Please make sure that you actually installed ServiceB into ServiceA. Do `systemctl disable ServiceB` to cleanup, and `systemctl enable ServiceB` to install. Does "ServiceB [...] start too" now?

Comment: @DanielT Thanks you so much. indeed it is works now after disabled the services manually and enabled it again ! i can see that after enabled serviceB, it is creating a "wants" folder for serviceA, and put there serviceB, so this is how it is creating the depencies, i wonder why it does not creates it after reboot ? 
do i have to disable and enable again after stopping the service ? Thanks again !!

Comment: No, you only need to disable and enable after editing. I do not want systemd to create the dependencies automatically. If it did so automatically, I would be unable to disable services I don't want.

Comment: @DanielT Thank you, Daniel, it is very clear now :)
not sure why I can't mark this answer with a green V tough XD

Comment: I'm surprised that this isn't a duplicate (the disable+enable part). Anyway, I am writing an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to tell `systemd` to reinstall the new `.wants` after editing `ServiceB.service`. There is nothing wrong with the `.service` files, and a systemctl start and stop work fine once the services are installed properly. Tell systemd to use the new code with the following commands:

```bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload # Or use `systemctl edit` next time, which does this automatically
sudo systemctl disable ServiceB.service # Applies the remove from multi-user.target.wants
sudo systemctl enable ServiceB.service # Actually installs to ServiceA.wants
```

systemd does not automatically reenable services on boot, and leaves you to do this separately for a reason. You want to be able to disable services, and that is done by deleting from the `.wants`. If it recreated dependencies automatically, you would not be able to disable services that are causing problems.